# What's the slope of a zero sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,H)$ be a complex smooth polarized projective variety of dimension $d$. Let $E \neq 0$ be a torsion-free sheaf on $X.$ Then the slope of $E$ with respect to $H$ is defined by
$$\mu(E) = \frac{\deg(E)}{\text{rk}(E)}, $$
where $\deg(E) = (c_1(E).c_1(H)^{d-1})$ in $\mathbb{Z},$ and $\text{rk}(E)$ is the rank of $E.$
If $E$ is torsion, then we define $\mu(E) = \infty.$
What about the case $E = 0?$ It's tempting to define
$$\mu(0) = -\infty,$$
since $0$ is an initial object in the category of coherent sheaves on $X.$ But I never saw the definition in the literature. Very often $\mu(0)$ is left undefined. Indeed, the zero sheaf is both torsion and torsion-free. If we view it as a torsion sheaf, then we can also define
$$\mu(0) = \infty.$$

So my question is:
$$\mu(0) = \frac{0}{0} = \ ?$$

Comment: Is there a reason beyond pure curiosity to do this? The purpose of the slope is to repackage the degree and rank in a different form for studying stability and moduli spaces, but I don't see where the zero sheaf would really come into play for this.

Comment: @TabesBridges I guess it's more of curiosity. For that, I also wonder if the zero sheaf is unstable.

Comment: The convention about $\mu(0)$ is up to you, you can definie in any way which seems to you convenient or beautiful, nothing really depends on it, because anyway, in the definition of stability you don't consider zero subscheaves (or quotient sheaves), and similarly in the notion of Harder-Narasimhan filtration you don't allow zero subquotients.

Comment: @Sasha That's right. The slope $\mu(0)=0/0$ phenomenon also aligns with that the reduced Hilbert polynomial of the zero sheaf is $0/0,$ which is undefined. Another related fact is that a zero sheaf has dimension $-\infty.$ So I will propose the convention $\mu(0) = -\infty.$